# How to get SSH message of the day (MOTD) using python's paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Couldn't find a way to get MOTD (`/etc/motd` file) after successful login. I use Paramiko but doing so with any other Python library would be great

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/motd` file is printed on an interactive terminal. As such there's no nice API to retrieve it from a non-interactive program.

Probably the only way is to open an interactive shell session using [`SSHClient.invoke_shell`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell) and read its output.

Instead, consider simply reading/downloading the `/etc/motd` file via SFTP ([`SFTPClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html)).